# Default values in java

Tags: java, initialization, instance-variables, local-variables

Hi I am having the following code. when i am using instance variables i am getting the output as follows(Default Values)

```
int value: 0
float value: 0.0
String value: null
Static int value: 0
```

But if i try declare the local variable and print the default value it is giving an error that the variable should be initialized. Can any one explain me the reason please?

```
public class DefaultValues {
  int a;
  float b;
  String c;
  static int d;
  public static void main(String[] args) {      
    int e;                                     // <----
    DefaultValues dv = new DefaultValues();
    System.out.println("int value: "+dv.a);
    System.out.println("float value: "+dv.b);
    System.out.println("String value: "+dv.c);
    System.out.println("Static int value: "+d);
    System.out.println("local int value: "+e); // <----
  }
}
```

Comment: Local variables do not have a default value. They must be initialized before they are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only instance variables, static(Class) variables and array components are initialized to default values.

Local variables cannot be used unless they are initialized as they are not assigned default values.

Comment: _are arrays_ Did you mean to say something else?

Comment: Yes **An array initializer creates an array and provides initial values for all its components** as per JLS.

Comment: Oh got your point now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From [Java Language Specification 3.0, 4.12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) Initial Values of Variables:

> A local variable (§14.4, §14.14) must be explicitly given a value
>   before it is used, by either initialization (§14.4) or assignment
>   (§15.26), in a way that can be verified by the compiler using the
>   rules for definite assignment (§16).

Answer (score 1):

We may have uninitialied local vars but compiler will not allow to use unless we explicitly intialize them. This is Java language rule. See JLS 4.12.5. Initial Values of Variables http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html

> •A local variable (§14.4, §14.14) must be explicitly given a value
>   before it is used, by either initialization (§14.4) or assignment
>   (§15.26), in a way that can be verified using the rules for definite
>   assignment (§16).

Answer (score 1):

For Class members(variable) JVM will put the default values or initialize it by default value, for a local variables it makes you assign and initial value before accessing the variable.

From Doc :

> It's not always necessary to assign a value when a field is declared.
>   Fields that are declared but not initialized will be set to a
>   reasonable default by the compiler. Generally speaking, this default
>   will be zero or null, depending on the data type. Relying on such
>   default values, however, is generally considered bad programming
>   style.

You can check the Default Values of different datatype in [Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) for more information about the class members default values.